# Geocode free APi for internal application

Tags: leaflet, geocoding, software-recommendations, nominatim, open-source-routing-machine

I need opinions / experienced use on this issue:

Which API can be used to geocode an internal application of a company that meets these requirements:

- Can be used for company internal application unlimitedly
- Returns the latitude and longitude of the address more precisely and not atrealada the vertices (as with OSM)

Right now I'm researching on Yahoo Maps on license terms. I want opinions from someone who has passed this need. My application is to design routes using OSRM and Leaflet. I'm currently using Nominatim Geocode which returns me the lat / long in accordance with the vertices when the address is in the middle of the street - this causes problems.

Comment: You can use Google Maps, although there is a limit to the amount and frequency of the requests. I used geopy  (python module) for my purpose which works as a charm.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most comprehensive Python geocoding library I have came across. Easy install using Pip

here is the link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder/1.8.0

You can geocode with Google maps up to 2,000 addresses per 24 hours, sign up for a free API key with bing maps (geocode 125,000 addresses per year) or you can use OpenStreetMap or OSM to I believe geocode as much as you need. Its very simple to use

*Bing maps is the fastest and it more often than not geocode the location in a parcel as opposed to the middle of the street compared to google or osm

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the geocoding tools available at [Texas A&M GeoServices?](http://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out our [Free Geocoding API](http://geocode.farm/). It sounds like we would be a perfect match for this.

**Disclaimer**: I work for Geocode Farm (the service that I am recommending).